# Prove a matrix in the form $A B A^T$ is not zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Consider a generic real matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and a square matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, where both have non-zero rank.

What assumptions may I need to prove that $rank(A B A^T) \neq 0$, or equivalently that $A B A^T$ is not the zero matrix ?

Examples:

- If $B$ is the identity matrix, it holds that $rank(A B A^T)=rank(AA^T)=rank(A)>0$
- If $B$ is a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal elements, it holds that $rank(A B A^T)=rank(A)>0$
- If $B$ is positive definite, it holds that $rank(A B A^T)=rank(A)>0$
- If $nullity(A)=nullity(B)=0$, it holds that $A B A^T \neq 0$
- If $nullity(A)<rank(BA^T)$, it holds that $A B A^T \neq 0$

Unfortunately the case I am studying does not fall in any of these examples.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the case that you're studying? That would probably make it easier to find a set of assumptions that might apply to your case

Comment: By the way, the usual term for "full rank and gram" is "positive definite"

Comment: A slight weakening of that third condition is that if $(B + B^T)$ is positive definite (i.e. "full rank and gram"), then $ABA^T$ is non-zero whenever $A$ is non-zero

Comment: For rank conditions, it suffices to have $B$ invertible and $\operatorname{rank}(A)>n/2$, so that $\dim\left(\operatorname{range}(BA^T)\cap\operatorname{range}(A^T)\right)>n/2 + n/2 - n=0$

Comment: @user1551 I think your answer is what i'm looking for, may you give me some more details and references to study this property of the dimension of the range?

Comment: @AndreaGiusti You should be able to find a reference regarding [Sylvester's rank inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties), which states that
$$
\operatorname{rank}(ABA^T) \geq \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(BA^T) - n,
$$
which for the case that $B$ is invertible and $\operatorname{rank}(A) > n/2$ implies that $\operatorname{rank}(A[BA^T]) > 0$.

Comment: Unfortunately Sylvester's and Frobenius' inequalities do not work in my case, because $m$, that is the number of columns of $A$, is larger than $ rank(A) +rank(BA^T)$.

Comment: @AndreaGiusti I suspect that user1551 was confusing $n$ and $m$ in their comment

Comment: @BenGrossmann Ah, you are right. I was lost in dimensions.